# What to put in HTML snapshot for hash-bang URL for SEO?

Tags: ajax, seo, googlebot, hashbang

I am using hash-bang URLs in my AJAX application and I am implementing the server-side for:

> handle ?_escaped_fragment_=key1=value1%26key2=value2

So when I look at Google's [FAQ](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/faq.html), it says that [this URL](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCheckBox) has an [equivalent snapshot](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html?_escaped_fragment_=CwRadioButton)

It is easy to see that the snapshot content is not the same as corresponding hash-bang url.  This Google example does not help and therefore my question:

My HTML page has three components/panels/sections  that are being  updated by AJAX. I use the `onclick` event  on the hash-bang URLs to fetch the  content from server and then update  relevant section of the HTML page.   My panels are updated independent of  each other and each panel has its own hash-bang URL .

My question  is:

Should the HTML snapshot contain the entire page with all 3 sections  or only the  updated section?

If I am to return the entire page, it is almost impossible to get the state of the other 2 sections correctly, so would the Googlebot reject my site if the other 2 sections are returned in their default state ?

Answer (score 0):

this is a good question, sadly no answer for this one :( im looking for the same. My problem is that EVERYTHING are news loaded with ajax, so each news is actually a little peace of text so im asking myself if my snapshots should be only the current new or a full page with all the info that i have in my home plus current new's content

Answer (score 0):

Do you have news about that topic ?